# Setting scrollTop when initializing jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jQuery plugin:

http://jsfiddle.net/2kbrfv9z/

The plugin works great, but I want to pass settings to the plugin so that I can set the ul on the right number.

When I initialize the plugin and I want to set the start time on 2:00:00 I add a scroll top on the ul to set the right li. (ul with value 0 is scrollTop(0) and 1 is scrollTop(35)). But I don't get it working.

Maybe I'm missing something.

I tried to set the scrolltop of the element. Without a result.

```
hourElement.scrollTop(70);
```

Comment: I'm able to get scrollTop working with a simple version of your site: https://jsfiddle.net/edjwv875/ so there must be something wrong with your logic. Are you able to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for me to look at as there is a lot of code in your jsfiddle?

Comment: When the plugin is initialized and I do a scroll top it works. But I want to pass trough the settings a start time. So when I intializing the plugin and I set the start time to 12:40:45 I have to set the right li's in the hour, minute and second ul. I tried this to do a calculation like this for hours scrollTop(12 * settings.height) but there happens nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Without a minimal reproducible example I can't dive too much into your code (as your jsfiddle is quite large) but I've created a small jsfiddle which contains a ul like yours with an li for every hour of the day and a button which, when clicked, jumps to the li which represents the current hour of the day.

For example the html looks like:

```
<button>
click me
</button>

<ul id="minutes">
    <li class="timeItem">1</li>
    <li class="timeItem">2</li>
    <li class="timeItem">3</li>
    <li class="timeItem">4</li>
    <li class="timeItem">5</li>
    <li class="timeItem">6</li>
    <li class="timeItem">7</li>
    <li class="timeItem">8</li>
    <li class="timeItem">9</li>
    <li class="timeItem">10</li>
    <li class="timeItem">11</li>
    <li class="timeItem">12</li>
    <li class="timeItem">13</li>
    <li class="timeItem">14</li>
    <li class="timeItem">15</li>
    <li class="timeItem">16</li>
    <li class="timeItem">17</li>
    <li class="timeItem">18</li>
    <li class="timeItem">19</li>
    <li class="timeItem">20</li>
    <li class="timeItem">21</li>
    <li class="timeItem">22</li>
    <li class="timeItem">23</li>
</ul>
```

and in the javascript I do:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('button').click(function()
    {
        var hour = new Date().getHours();
        // the hour of the day * the height of one li
        // less 30 to account for the li starting on hour 1
        var toScroll = (hour * 30) - 30;
        $('ul').scrollTop(toScroll);
    });
});
```

It seems to work as you desire. If you provide a minimal reproducible example I can look into your code more specifically, in the meantime you can find the fiddle [here.](https://jsfiddle.net/9cjf13wr/)

Comment: It works because everything is loaded. But I am creating a plugin. So not everything is loaded. I am initializing the plugin and when the  plugin is intialized the scrollTop has to be what I am setting.